# UnicodeDecodeError: to read a locale configuration file

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following file

```
In [5]: !cat /usr/bin/locale | head -n 3                                                                               
>�����P�P�P��$h%���������DDP�td<�<�<���Q�tdR�tdP�P�P���/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2GNUGNU���t�g6����SҶ��p���S
=B!4F;?"38%yG\��w'.MSec>�^��e�n�[�[ N�m
�X���v�!�WA}sx+j 1�7��fgetscallocstrlentsearchp
osix_spawn_file_actions_initstrstrstrcspn__errno_locationopen64memcmp__fxstat64stdoutfputsposix_spawn_file_actions_dest
roymemcpyfclosemallocnl_langinfoopendir__xstat64__ctype_b_locgetenvstderrmunmap_obstack_newchunkposix_spawn_file_action
s_adddup2fscanfscandirtextdomaintwalkstrchrobstack_freefprintfalphasort__stpcpyfdopenreaddir64qsortargp_parse__cxa_fina
lizeargz_create_sepposix_spawnp_obstack_beginstrcmp__libc_start_mainstrcoll__overflow__environGLIBC_2.3GLIBC_2.15GLIBC_
2.14GLIBC_2.4GLIBC_2.2.5_ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable__gmon_start___ITM_registerTMCloneTable
)u   ������ii
```

I plan to decode it for reading

```
 In [6]: fin = open('/usr/bin/locale', 'r')                                                                             

In [8]: data = fin.read()                                                                                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-57f1cb056244> in <module>
----> 1 data = fin.read()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
    320         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    321         data = self.buffer + input
--> 322         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    323         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    324         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 41: invalid continuation byte
```

The information about the file

```
In [10]: !file /usr/bin/locale                                                                                         
/usr/bin/locale: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linu
x-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=f3fee574a96736969ce794ed53d2b6cef870c7fe, stripped                  

In [11]: !ls -l /usr/bin/locale                                                                                        
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 54688 Aug 24  2018 /usr/bin/locale
```

How could I read the content to a variable for further manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a binary executable file.  It does not contain the configuration.

If you are looking for all of the supported locales, use the file `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED`

If you are looking for the systems default locale:(not on all systems)
`/etc/local.conf`

To get the current users locale in `python`:

```
import os;

print(os.environ['LANG'])
#prints locale.encoding en_US.UTF8

print(os.environ['LANGUAGE'])
# prints en_US
```

---

To run locale and get its output into a string(most consistent across Linux/Unix):

```
import subprocess
locale = subprocess.getoutput("/usr/bin/locale ")
```

You can use any valid parameters to locale in the above code.

Comment: Python does not have library to cat or read binary file directly? suppose not convert to utf-8.

Comment: use `mode='rb' to read a file as binary. This will skip the UTF8 decoding and return bytes back on calls to `read()`.

Comment: thank you. I notice that getoutpt is labeled as old api, run(capture_output) is recommended.